# How to add JBOSS EAP 7.2 server in eclipse kepler (Sts 3.4) as there is no adapter service available for 7.2

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-kepler, jboss-eap-7

I am using STS 3.4 and I want to setup JBOSS EAP 7.2.
As I saw that there is no specific adapter service for JBOSS EAP 7.2.

So which adapter service do I need to chose?

I tried using JBoss EAP 6.1+ Runtime Server adapter service but it is giving me problems in the startup and shutdown.

As the server gets started but the process of starting continues even though it prints that server is started on console. 
And then it stops after encountering the timeout.

So which adapter should I need to use?

Or do I need to upgrade my STS?

Comment: Not sure but upgrade to eclipse mars may work more than upgrade your STS

Comment: You could check inside the folder Red Hat JBoss Middleware>Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7.1,could you check this?If this is not available please update sts to a more recent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me upgrading the STS worked. As the issue clearly was regarding the adapter. I tried downloading JBOSS tools from the eclipse marketplace, but I got some error. So I finally upgraded STS.

Another hack would be using the same eclipse and increasing the server start time for jboss to something which is in hours, in such case it does not get timeout, but you cant use this in production environment and only for developers like me, who want a instant fix for some time.